# No redireccionar al Home , al registrar usuario en laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Hola estoy haciendo uso de Auth en laravel 5.8 por lo que al momento de registrar un usuario, me lleva al home luego de registrarlo, la idea es que no se valla al home y pueda seguir agregando mas usuarios ya que me redirecciona logueado con el usuario que se registro, en el controlador de register solo sale la funcion create y validator pero no hay ninguna redirección.

Agregue un back() para ver si funcionaba, pero me sigue llevando al home con la sesion iniciada del nuevo usuario ingresado

```
  protected function create(array $data)
{
    
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'nivel' => 0,
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);

    return back()->with('Listo','Asistencia ingresada correctamente');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

La documentación [de Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#included-authenticating) nos indica que posterior al registro de un usuario este es redirigido como parte de la lógica establecida en el *RouteServiceProvider* derivado del valor asignado a esta constante:

```
public const HOME = '/home';
```

Entonces basándonos en la misma fuente, lo que podemos hacer es anular ese comportamiento y establecer la ruta personalizada como la del register así:

```
public const HOME = 'register';
```

**Nota**

Es importante tener en cuenta que el recurso a donde seamos redirigidos de forma predeterminada depende del paquete que usemos:

- Si usamos *jetstream en Laravel 8 o superior* entonces nos manda a *dashboard* luego del registro
- Si no usamos jetstream y por ejemplo usamos *laravel/ui* entonces nos redirige a *home*

De ahi en adelante el cambio sugerido debería funcionar igual

**Edito**

Para que el usuario creado no quede logueado de *forma automática*, ve al controller *Registersusers.php* y comenta o elimina esta línea:

```
$this->guard()->login($user);
```

Ya que el método login perteneciente al *SessionGuard.php* toma al objeto `$user` recién creado y realiza lo siguiente (*de acuerdo con el propio código fuente*):

> Log a user into the application.

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por responder, al ver lo que mencionas  eso funciona para laravel8, se me olvido mencionar que estoy usando laravel 5.8 de todas formas revise la documentación y pude cambiar la ruta donde te redirige, el problema es que te redirige logueado con el usuario que se registro, siendo que deberia quedar la session del admin que registro en este caso

Comment: Por eso aclaro en la misma respuesta que sin importar que paquete uses la forma para redireccionar es la misma, ahhh ese detalle de que se debe mantener la sesión del usuario actual no la mencionaste en la pregunta, deja edito

Comment: @FelipeAndresLarraguibelAray revisa si la edición te sirve

Comment: no lamentablemente no me sirvio el archivo Registersusers.php no lo encuentro solo se hace uso de el en registerController pero no se donde agregar lo que me mencionas ya que el archivo no le encuentro, de  todas formas tendre que crear un controlador nuevo para registrar. Muchas gracias  por tu tiempo